# When to use GeometricTransformation or Rotate

Tags: graphics, animation

OI think that I am committing a basic error that may want to close it, but I am not finding where I am wrong.

This is my code:

```
r1 = 15; r2 = 8; c = 50; γ = ArcSin[(r1 - r2)/c] // N;
l1 = (2 γ + π) r1
l2 = (π - 2 γ) r2
l3 = 2 c Cos[γ]
L = 2 c Cos[γ] + (2 γ + π) r1 + (π - 2 γ) r2
```

Here I am creating a graphic:

```
g=Graphics[{Circle[{0,0},r1,{π/2-γ,((3*π))/2+γ}],
Circle[{c,0},r2,{π/2-γ,-(π/2)+γ}],
Line[{{Cos[π/2-γ]*r1,Sin[π/2-γ]*r1},{Cos[π/2-γ]*r2+c,Sin[π/2-γ]*r2}}],
Line[{{Cos[((3*π))/2+γ]*r1,Sin[((3*π))/2+γ]*r1},{Cos[-(π/2)+γ]*r2+c,Sin[-(π/2)+γ]*r2}}],
PointSize[0.03],
Point[{0,0}],
Point[{c,0}],
PlotRange->{{-100,-100},{100,100}}}]
```

[image]

I want my animation turn in point {0,0}, but something is wrong.

What would it be?

```
img = Rotate[g, #, {0, 0}] & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6]

Export["Motion.gif", img]
```

Comment: -1 for too many fake edits. Namely, edits with the sole purpose of bumping your post on top of the stack of active questions. Also, please refrain doing minor edits on several questions at the same time. Refer to this [policy](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), and for further comments join this [meta discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2026/31159).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There were some strange characters in your code (/2 as one Unicode code). Might have been caused by copying your code here. Anyway I corrected them here.

The solution to your problem is the use of `GeometricTransformation`, which you can apply on graphics *elements*, not a `Graphics` object as a whole. Therefore, I removed the `Graphics` part from g and applied `GeometricTransformation` to it. `Rotate` is used to rotate any Mathematica object (not only graphics) and is not suited for this task, as its operation is difficult to align with underlying graphics coordinates.

```
g = {Circle[{0, 0}, r1, {Pi/2 - γ, ((3*Pi))/2 + γ}],     
     Circle[{c, 0}, r2, {Pi/2 - γ, -(Pi/2) + γ}],     
     Line[{{Cos[Pi/2 - γ]*r1, 
      Sin[Pi/2 - γ]*r1}, {Cos[Pi/2 - γ]*r2 + c, 
      Sin[Pi/2 - γ]*r2}}],     Line[{{Cos[((3*Pi))/2 + γ]*r1, 
      Sin[((3*Pi))/2 + γ]*r1}, {Cos[-(Pi/2) + γ]*r2 + c,
       Sin[-(Pi/2) + γ]*r2}}], Dashed, PointSize[0.03],     
     Point[{0, 0}], Point[{c, 0}]};

Graphics[GeometricTransformation[g, RotationMatrix[#]] & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi,Pi/6]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Exporting to an animation:

```
Export["D:\\Users\\Sjoerd\\Desktop\\test.gif", 
 Graphics[GeometricTransformation[g, RotationMatrix[#]], 
    PlotRange -> {{-70, 70}, {-70, 70}}] & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/20]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, you could also use `RotationTransform` instead of `RotationMatrix`.

Comment: @ChipHurst Yeah, but `RotationMatrix` is 4 characters less ;-)

Comment: To shorten the code further, one could directly use `RotationMatrix /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6]` as the second argument of `GeometricTransform`.